# Is it safe to modify useRef value inside useMemo react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a custom react hook that accepts a value, checks if it deeply equal to its previous value, then return the previous if equal, otherwise return the new value.

Currently, I am doing:

```
function useOldIfSame<Data> (value: Data): Data {
  const cacheRef = useRef<Data>(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEqual(value, cacheRef.current)) {
      cacheRef.current = value;
    }
  }, [value]);

  return useMemo(() => isEqual(value, cacheRef.current) ? cacheRef.current : value, [value]);
}
```

Above works as intended, but I realize that `isEqual` will be called two times if the `value` is changed and may impact performance on large objects. So I come up with this approach:

```
function useOldIfSame<Data> (value: Data): Data {
  const cacheRef = useRef<typeof value>(value);

  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!isEqual(cacheRef.current, value)) {
      cacheRef.current = value;
    }

    return cacheRef.current;
  }, [value]);
}
```

Is this second approach safe? If yes, is it an anti-pattern?

I'm not sure if modifying `useRef` values is considered as side-effect (as doing side effects inside `useMemo` is not safe and is an anti-pattern) so I am having a hard time in choosing which approach to use.

Comment: I can't immediately think of any issues with this implementation. What makes you think the `useMemo` callback needs to be a pure function?

Comment: To what I know, `useMemo` is used to cache result of expensive operation, and `useEffect` is used to do some things if some value changes. With that, the first thing that comes into my mind is that `useMemo` should only do the expensive operation and return the result (should not do set value like operations, like a pure function), and `useEffect` should do the set value like operations.